# How to set delegates to access from different methods

Tags: objective-c, macos, delegates, nswindow

I have some code where I'm trying to show my prefwindow with a method, but I cut out the rest and left the window init and the other method. So how would I access objects across methods?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
@interface hello : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
    NSWindow *prefwindow;
}

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;

-(void)openPrefs;

@end

@implementation hello;
@synthesize window;

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    hello *self = [[hello alloc] init]; 
    [NSAutoreleasePool new];
    [NSApplication sharedApplication];

    id prefwindow = [[[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 350, 150)
                                                 styleMask:(NSTitledWindowMask | NSClosableWindowMask) backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:NO]
                     autorelease];
    [prefwindow center];
    [prefwindow setTitle:appName];
    [prefwindow setDelegate:self];
    [self openPrefs];

    [NSApp setDelegate:self];
    [NSApp run];
    return 0;
}

-(void)openPrefs {
    [NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps: YES];
    [prefwindow makeKeyAndOrderFront: self];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have access to the "prefwindow" variable of the "hello" class inside the main function. It's out of scope. In order to change the variable, I believe you'll want to write

```
self.prefwindow = ...
```

Comment: Someone correct me if I'm using the wrong terms. It's been a while since I programmed in Obj-C.

Comment: forgot about that part, and I know, ive been on here for a while hhaah

Answer (score 0):

With `id prefwindow =` you are declaring a new object called `prefWindow`. If you want to use the one you declare in the header, don't declare it again. Do just:

```
prefwindow = [[[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 350, 150)
                                             styleMask:(NSTitledWindowMask | NSClosableWindowMask) backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:NO]
                 autorelease];
```

What you did is just declaring a new object called the same way as the one you declare in the header.

Comment: now i get `../hello.m: In function ‘main’:
../hello.m:69: error: ‘prefwindow’ undeclared (first use in this function)
../hello.m:69: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
../hello.m:69: error: for each function it appears in.)
`

Comment: it says its not declared even though i did it in interface

Comment: You cannot access the variables in the "hello" class inside of a function... You have to do that from inside a method of the class. In other words, prefwindow is *out of scope* inside your main function.